# jQuery .change() method does not work for dynamically created check-box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create a cascade of elements dynamically.

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-2 text-primary" for="prix">Prix:</label>      
<div class="col-sm-10"> 
    <select  name="prix" id="prix">
        <option value="0">Type de prix</option>
        <option value="1">Gratuit</option>
        <option value="2">Montant</option>
        <option value="3">Echange</option>
        <option value="4">Prix à discuter</option>
        <option value="5">Prix n'est pas d'application</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select_prix" ></div>
<div id="select_offre" ></div>
```

When I choose option `value="2"`, a checkbox have to be inserted into div `id="select_prix"`

So I use jquery:

```
$('#prix').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() < 2) {
        $("#select_prix").empty();
    }  

    var stroffre  ='<label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-primary">Offre ?                                  </label>';
    stroffre +='<div class="checkbox col-sm-10">';
    stroffre +='<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">';
    stroffre +='<input class="sr-only" id="chkoffre" type="checkbox" value="">';
    stroffre +='<span class="checkbox-label">Autoriser les  offres</span>';
    stroffre +='</label> </div>';

    if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        $("#select_prix").append(stroffre);
    }
});
```

Ok. The checkbox appears and what I get is:

> *checkbox* ' Autoriser les offres'

Now, when I select checkbox , I want to insert a new line input into div `id="select_offre"`

I made for that a new jQuery code:

```
$("#chkoffre").change(function () {
    alert( 'CheckboxOffre' ); // or $(this).val()
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {

    }else{

    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the alert message.

Comment: You have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Take a look at [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for doing that:

```
$("#chkoffre").on("change", function(){
    alert( 'CheckboxOffre' ); // or $(this).val()
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {

   }else{

   }
});
```

This known as event delegation.

Comment: Close, but not quite. Delegation is the correct method, but the code you provided is not a proper delegate. You need to provide a selector to an existing element for the delegate to bind to in the first part, then provide a more specific selector as the second argument in the .on method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In order to listen for an event on an element that has been dynamically added to the DOM, you have to use a event delegate and not a directly bound event handler. As mentioned in the jQuery api documentation for .on, "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()". http://api.jquery.com/on/ This is true for .change and other direct bound event types.

So this:

```
$("#chkoffre").change(function () {
```

Must be changed to this:

```
$("#select_prix").on("change", "#chkoffre", function () {
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates this fix when applied to your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/uuvcyf9o/
Here's the full code:

```
$('#prix').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() < 2) {
        $("#select_prix").empty();
    }  

    var stroffre  ='<label class="col-sm-2 control-label text-primary">Offre ?</label>';
    stroffre +='<div class="checkbox col-sm-10">';
    stroffre +='<label class="checkbox-custom" data-initialize="checkbox">';
    stroffre +='<input class="sr-only" id="chkoffre" type="checkbox" value="">';
    stroffre +='<span class="checkbox-label">Autoriser les  offres</span>';
    stroffre +='</label></div>';

    if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        $("#select_prix").append(stroffre);
    }
});

$("#select_prix").on("change", "#chkoffre", function () {
    alert( 'CheckboxOffre' ); // or $(this).val()
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    }else{
    }
});
```