# jquery add new checkbox, when clicked the new checkbox, it happens nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have three tables. They all contains some checkboxes. when a checkbox in the first table is checked, it will add some new checkboxs into the second table. But when I check a checkbox in the second table, it happens nothing. It seems that the checkbox event only observe the checkbox in the first table. Following is the episode of my js code.

```
function bindEvent4CheckboxArea() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    initController.initGlobalData(false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('trade') >= 0) {
          var tradeId = $(this).attr('id');
          var tradeIdByInt = tradeId.substring(6);
          globalVar.userSelectedTrade.push(tradeId);
          if (tradeIdByInt < 100) {
            globalVar.userSelectedFirstTrade.push(tradeIdByInt);
          } else if (tradeIdByInt < 10000) {
            globalVar.userSelectedSecondTrade.push(tradeIdByInt);
          }

        } else {
          globalVar.userSelectedIndex.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
      }
    });
    //add new checkbox into the second table
    render.drawTradeInfoArea('#second_trade');
    // add new checkbox into the third table
    render.drawTradeInfoArea('#third_trade');

  });
}
```

Comment: This is duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052013/jquery-change-method-does-not-work-for-dynamically-created-check-box          in short, you need to delegate the event to the parent container as the event that you binded to the checkbox is only for existing checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Try below code if it is working. As some checkboxes are generated dynamically so you have to use jQuery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you compare my codes with yours then you can find I have changed 2nd line of code.

```
function bindEvent4CheckboxArea() {
      $( "body" ).on( "change", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
        initController.initGlobalData(false);
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('trade') >= 0) {
              var tradeId = $(this).attr('id');
              var tradeIdByInt = tradeId.substring(6);
              globalVar.userSelectedTrade.push(tradeId);
              if (tradeIdByInt < 100) {
                globalVar.userSelectedFirstTrade.push(tradeIdByInt);
              } else if (tradeIdByInt < 10000) {
                globalVar.userSelectedSecondTrade.push(tradeIdByInt);
              }

            } else {
              globalVar.userSelectedIndex.push($(this).attr('id'));
            }
          }
        });
        //add new checkbox into the second table
        render.drawTradeInfoArea('#second_trade');
        // add new checkbox into the third table
        render.drawTradeInfoArea('#third_trade');

      });

}
```

Please try and let me know if it working.